# routes from backend API for content management in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

An Angular 2 app uses the following code to load an array of routes:

```
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes);
```

Currently, the `myRoutes` array is defined in the Angular 2 app, and works perfectly.  But this assumes that routes have been defined statically in the client app.

> **How can the `myRoutes` array be fed into `RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes)` from a source that would allow users do define routes and content from a user interface in a separate administration app?**  This would involve feeding the user-defined routes through a backend server.

I figured out how to send a `data` argument into each `Route` object in the `myRoutes` array, so that the same component can be re-used for multiple routes by sending different config into the same component from each route.  But how can the routes array be imported from an external data store in a backend server?

> [This link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4234) indicates that I am describing a feature request.  However, There MUST be some way to have UI-based content management in Angular 2 without having to resort to third party tools.  **What is a minimalist approach to importing an array of routes into `RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes)` from a backend server?**

Answer (score 0):

You could try using dynamic component loading. The docs for it are here: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

I have not tried it ... but it does not look like it does *exactly* what you want. It does not seem to provide a way to add dynamic routes. But it does allow adding dynamic components.

Also, as per the link you defined, this is an issue with the CLI and its dependence on Web pack and AOT. You may be able to achieve more of what you want using SystemJS as your module loader.

Comment: I can think to create a server-side service that creates/over-writes a file in the Angular2 app to define a `const` containing the routes.  The administration app would trigger re-writing the file with the `const` every time an administrator changes the routes.  This way the Angular app could work the same way importing the routes from the file containing the `const`.  But this seems like a hack to me.  Hard to maintain.  Almost an unnatural act.  I am reaching out for a better way.  I am not sure how to frame the question in SO format.